# Automation of social media account creation by using python3 and pyautogui

Tags: python-3.x, linux, pandas, automation, pyautogui

Hi everyone i am working on a project to automate the creation of social media account .For this i have an api which provide me phone no and OTP. So basically my first script is fetching phone no and Otp from that api and the second one is clicking buttons and filling forms.
My problem is i am unable to fill the forms because my main function is stuck in a loop because i am not sending any otp to that api. If anybody has any suggestions about how to integrate these two scripts please share your idea with me. I am sharing my both scripts.
Thanks in advance.

This is the code to fetch phone no and otp from api.

```
import requests
import json
import time


# This main function takes the value of tzid and call the api inbuild function to print the
# state of operation which has  {response: RESPONSE, service: SERVICE, number: NOMER, msg: ANSWER}

def main(tzid):

    result2 = requests.get("http://api.sms-reg.com/getState.php?tzid=" +tzid+ "&apikey=my_api_key")
    #time.sleep(20)
    xyz = result2.text
    y = json.loads(xyz)
    print(y)

    if(y["response"] != "TZ_NUM_PREPARE"):          #if response is not equal to "TZ_NUM_PREPARE"
        main(tzid)                                  #call the function again and again until we
                                                    #get response == "TZ_NUM_PREPARE"

    elif(y["response"] == "TZ_NUM_PREPARE"):
        print(y["number"])
        time.sleep(5)
        result3 =requests.get("http://api.sms-reg.com/setReady.php?tzid=" +tzid+ "&apikey=my_api_key")

        z = result3.text                            # result3 call api inbuilt setReady method which
        zx = json.loads(z)                          # tell api that the number is ready for operation
        print(z)


        if(zx["response"] == "1"):                  #if we get response 1 for result3 it means number is
            time.sleep(15)                          #now ready for operation

            result4 = requests.get("http://api.sms-reg.com/getState.php?tzid=" +tzid+ "&apikey=my_api_key")
            r_xyx = result4.text
            r_y = json.loads(r_xyx)                 #result4 is similar to result 2 , this process is repeated
                                                    #because we want updated data which contains OTP

            if(r_y["response"] != "TZ_NUM_ANSWER"):  #if the response does not contains OTP call the function
                main(tzid)                           #again and again

            else:
                #print(r_y["answer"])                #print otp
                print(r_y["answer"])








#Driver Code
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # result = requests.get send request to the api to fetch data
    # Basically it provides us two parameters "response" and "tzid"
    result = requests.get('http://api.sms-reg.com/getNum.php?country=ru&service=gmail&apikey=my_api_key')
    id = result.text                    #id fetch the data in text form
    x = json.loads(id)                  #x loads the text into json
    tzid = str(x["tzid"])               #variable tzid fetch the value from json
    #print(tzid)
    print(tzid)
    main(tzid)
```

And thsi is the code where i want my phone no and otp

```
import pyautogui
import time
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json
import fetchapidata

df = pd.read_csv("input.csv")

df0 = df ["name1"]
df1 = df ["job"]
df2 = df ["name2"]
df3 = df ["name3"]
df4 = df ["name4"]

for i in range(1):
    #print(df0[i],df1[i])

 pyautogui.click(1308, 170)      #click on the small account logo

 time.sleep(5)

 pyautogui.click(1159, 527)      #clicks on the sign out button

 time.sleep(4)

 pyautogui.click(1270, 169)      #clicks on the sign in button

 time.sleep(4.5)

 pyautogui.click(620, 468)       #clicks on remove account

 time.sleep(2.5)

 pyautogui.click(888, 396)      #clicks on remove logo

 time.sleep(3.5)

 pyautogui.click(802, 528)     #clicks on yes remove


 #pyautogui.click(675, 422)          #add another account
 time.sleep(5)


 pyautogui.click(580, 601)         #create account

 time.sleep(6)

 pyautogui.click(594, 654)         #for myself

 time.sleep(4)

 pyautogui.click(450, 345)         #firstname

 pyautogui.write(df0[i],interval=0.5)

 time.sleep(2)

 pyautogui.click(641, 344)         #lastname

 pyautogui.write(df1[i],interval=0.5)

 time.sleep(1.5)

 pyautogui.click(453, 407)         #userid

 pyautogui.write(df2[i],interval=0.4)

 time.sleep(1.8)

 pyautogui.click(423, 515)        #password

 pyautogui.write(df3[i],interval=0.4)

 time.sleep(1.4)

 pyautogui.click(592, 516)       #cnfrm password

 pyautogui.write(df4[i],interval=0.6)

 time.sleep(0.5)

 pyautogui.click(706, 637)      #done button

 time.sleep(7)


 pyautogui.click(516, 452)                  #click on the phone no field

 time.sleep(3)


x = fetchapidata.callingfun()

pyautogui.write(y, interval=0.2)  #enters phone no

 time.sleep(1)

 pyautogui.click(705, 532)

 time.sleep(5)

 pyautogui.click(449, 480)            #clicks on otp box

 time.sleep(1.5)

 pyautogui.write(r_y, interval=0.2)          #enters otp

 time.sleep(1)

 pyautogui.click(710, 570)           #clicks verify button

 time.sleep(6)

 pyautogui.click(414, 580)           #clicks month section

 time.sleep(1)

 pyautogui.click(415, 359)           #selects the month

 time.sleep(0.5)

 pyautogui.click(533, 585)          #click on day section

 pyautogui.write("1")               #write day

 time.sleep(0.5)

 pyautogui.click(664, 585)          #clicks on year

 time.sleep(0.3)

 pyautogui.write("2000")            #write in year section

 time.sleep(0.2)

 pyautogui.click(423, 669)         #click on gender

 time.sleep(0.2)

 pyautogui.click(401, 735)                  #select gender

 time.sleep(1.5)

 pyautogui.scroll(-100)

 time.sleep(0.5)

 pyautogui.click(697, 638)                 #click on next button

 time.sleep(8)

 pyautogui.click(621, 618)                 #click on skip button

 pyautogui.moveTo(189, 589)

 time.sleep(0.1)

 pyautogui.scroll(-100)

 time.sleep(0.4)

 pyautogui.click(699, 642)                #click on agree button

 time.sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 1):

Import your program in another program as module and call your functions in another program. Also break your main function into two parts .Call result 3 and 4 in another function and call both fuctions in another program.